# Express.js JWT always returns default 404 error on successful authorization

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

I am trying to perform JWT authorization but it returns the Express.js default 404 error page (HTML page not my defined error handler) on EVERY request when authorization is successful.

This won't happen if there is no token or an invalid one. Unauthorized error and all routes work fine without the token header.

I highly suspect that the problem is in `return next()` in `authHandler` but I don't know the reason.

The order of middlewares in app.js:

```js
//Authorization
app.use(authHandler);

//Routes
app.use(routes);

//Method 404 middleware
app.use(errorHandler.notFound);

//Generic error handler middleware
app.use(errorHandler.generic);
```

authHandler:

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

exports.userHeader = async (req, _res, next) => {
  if (req.headers && req.headers.authorization) {
    jwt.verify(
      req.headers.authorization,
      process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      (err, decode) => {
        if (!err) {
          req.user = decode;
          return next();
        }
      }
    );
  }

  req.user = undefined;
  return next();
};
```

Protected route:

```js
posts.get('/', user_handler.login_required, post_controller.index);
```

login_required handler:

```js
async (req, _res, next) => {
  if (req.user) {
    return next();
  }

  let error = new Error('Unauthorized');
  error.status = 401;
  return next(error);
};
```

Error response:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Cannot GET /posts</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked your routes?

Comment: @GetSet Yes, if there is no token header and authorization everything works as it should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `authHandler`. The `next()` must be in the outer scope `if` or it won't work. I don't know how it exactly made such a problem but it's like that its execution context or something is different so express raises an error.

It would be great if someone could demystify this situation.

authHandler:

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

exports.userHeader = async (req, _res, next) => {
  if (req.headers && req.headers.authorization) {
    jwt.verify(
      req.headers.authorization,
      process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      (err, decode) => {
        if (!err) {
          req.user = decode;
        }
      }
    );

    return next(); // This needs to be here
  }

  req.user = undefined;
  return next();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code. It's worked correctly by little change for me.
just put `req.user = undefined;
  return next();` in else statement like this `else{  req.user = undefined;
  return next();}`

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the broken authorization but the root problem was invoking `next()` in verify callback. I moved the `next()` outer in `if` and it works now.